# cannot convert from sf::renderwindow* to sf::renderwindow* - where am i going wrong?

Tags: c++, sfml

> C2664 'Camera::Camera(sf::RenderWindow *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'sf::RenderWindow *' to 'sf::RenderWindow *'

those two types look identical to me; am i missing something?

main.cppm

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

import camera;

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Ghost Engine");

    Camera cam(&window);

    return 0;
}
```

camera.ixx

```
export module camera;

#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

import entity;

export class Camera : public Entity {
sf::RenderWindow* window;

public:
    Camera(sf::RenderWindow* win) : window(win) {

    }
};
```

i am, admittedly, very new to c++ and i assume this problem stems from my lack of experience. any help is much appreciated, thank you!! :)

Comment: You should tell us more about your compiler flags. Is `--std=c++20` actually enabled?

Comment: yep- the language standard is set to c++20 in the config properties of VS, and all the proper libraries are linked.

Comment: Is that the first error message in the output?

Comment: it is; the first and only.